# Merging a semicircle with two parallel lines

Tags: adobe-illustrator

How can I merge a semicircle with two parallel lines? I want to have the leftmost point of the semicircle to bind with the leftmost line in the illustration below, and I'd like the rightmost point of the semicircle to be bound to the rightmost line simultaneously:

[image]

I'm using Illustrator (16.0.3).

Comment: It's got to be a circular arc. I don't want to use splines.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are trying to recreate paths from a scan. I've had to do this more times than I care to admit. Try this:

[image]

If you can't read the image, the steps are:

1. Draw the circle
2. Draw a rectangle, snapping the corners to the nodes on the circle.
3. Select both, rotate around the center of the circle
4. <kbd>Pathfinder > Weld</kbd>

Comment: Hmm... This is good. Thank you. Perhaps you might be able to help me with a [second question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25550/how-can-one-save-a-2d-part-that-is-as-connected-paths-in-illustrator-so-that).

Comment: I think I already may have. :)

Comment: Did you download the .ai file I linked to in the second question? I can't seem to tell if all the lines are connected. Do you have any familiarity with issues that might occur in sending these path files to a laser cutting company? If there is a small 0.01mm gap between paths will the laser go berserk?

Comment: Let's keep the comment for the other question over there. I'll go look at the file.

Answer (score 1):

Align the end anchors using the **Direct Selection Tool** (the white arrow), select the aligned anchors (still using the Direct Selection Tool), and then choose `Object > Path > Join` from the menu.

Or you could simply use [VectorScribe's](http://www.astutegraphics.com/software/vectorscribe/) Dynamic Corners tool on a rectangle...

[image: corners]

<sub>Note: I am not compensated for mentioning VectorScribe.</sub>

Comment: Well, if you were compensated, you'd be getting a kickback right now. I'mma bought to go buy that!

Comment: @TunaMaxx The Astute Plugins (all of them) are **by far** worth every penny. Much more so than any other AI plug in I've ever seen.. including the old Kai plug ins (if you remember those).

Answer (score 0):

While Scott's answer is excellent and simple, it's sometimes a hassle to align the arc and the lines.  That's why I thought I'll suggest a different approach, which I admit can also be a hassle. But another perspective never hurts. I've used your image as an example. The letters between parenthesis indicate the keyboard shortcut.

1. Make a rectangle that has the same heigth as the distance between the two parallel lines and rotate it such that it fits the image:
   [image]
2. Delete the lower line with the `Direct Selection Tool (A)`.
   [image]
3. Cut the lines with the `Scissors Tool (C)` at the appropriate place by clicking on the place where you want to make the cut. Delete the unnecessary parts of the line.
   [image]
   [image]
4. Measure the width of the rectangle, i.e. the distance between the two parallel lines. The `Measurement Tool` is found under the icon of the `Eye Dropper Tool`. Drag from point 1 to point 2 and read out the distance marked by `D`. In this case it's 340px.
   [image]
   [image]
5. Select the rectangle (or what's left of it) with the `Selection Tool (V)`. Go to `Effect -> Stylize -> Round Corners`. Type in 340/2 as the radius:
   [image]
6. And this is your result:
   [image]

Nice thing is that this scales as you scale the "rectangle" and you can change the radius later on by going to the `Appearence` pane and clicking on the underlined `Round Corners` link.
[image]

Comment: The rounded end looks a little wonky. Is it just an artifact of the screen shot, or did Rounded Corners actually product that hump on the right side?

Comment: It's not a hump, it just doesn't align correctly with the underlying image. One could decrease the radius slightly to hug the corner a little tighter. Or the rectangle can be scaled down a bit. But the `Weld` options works better anyway.