# How can one save a 2D part--that is, as connected paths--in Illustrator so that it can be "read" by AutoCAD?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, export, autodesk-sketchbook-pro, autocad

How can one save a 2D part--that is, as connected paths--in Illustrator so that it can be "read" by AutoCAD?

Comment: I can provide a link to a download of the file if necessary.

Comment: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/69SamUwP3/

Answer (score 1):

Go to <kbd>File > Export...</kbd>

Set "Save as type:" to AutoCAD Drawing (*.DWG)

Comment: Yes, but how do I know that my manufacturer will be able to read it in his AutoCAD correctly? This part will be lasered out of metal. I keep sending him files, but he keeps saying that there are no lines in the file. Perhaps you have AutoCAD, and you can check.

Comment: FYI, "lasere"d apparently isn't a word. I checked the OED--how sad. Perhaps "lased" is more correct, seeing how "lase" is a word.

Comment: Ahh, I get it. I don't have AutoCAD to test for you, but I send files exported this way out on a semi regular basis to a sub contractor. I've never had him tell me there was no lines in the file. Do your Illustrator paths have a stroke and/or a fill? Alternately, you can export as a DXF instead of a DWG.

Comment: I just sent .dxf, .dwg, and .svg. Those are the files he can apparently handle. Is there an AutoCAD friendly stackexchange?

Comment: Your Illustrator file had a bunch of open paths. Take a look at this .ai file, or the .dwg and .dxf files: http://www.fileswap.com/dl/rCqa6LLcj/ , http://www.fileswap.com/dl/5COELWjbSC/ , http://www.fileswap.com/dl/kMg9Teg1vl/

Comment: Are these the closed-form versions of my original? Actually, I see now. Did you preserve the ratio architecture; that is, the dimension proportionality?

Comment: The .ai file is identical with just the open paths all closed. The DWG and DXF files were exported 1:1 but I can't guarantee anything on them.

Comment: I opened the **dwg** and **dxf** files provided by @TunaMaxx in AutoCAD 2014. The file itself is fine, however, the fact that the shape is filled is a bit alien to most CAD users. So i would eliminate that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to guarantee things will work perfectly, that's why you find the functionality under <kbd>file > export</kbd>. One of the real problems of illustrator is that the *bezier splines* used by illustrator can not do **perfect** circular arcs, so what you get is just approximate. This may be fine in many cases but for general mechanical engineering this is a big problem.